# GAN artifacts on borders

Tags: neural-networks, convolution, noise, gan

not quite a math-question, but I have a doubt.

I'm trying to build from scratch the Pix2pix network, on the facades dataset, and I think I finally got a good model (from the paper I borrowed just the idea, the model structure I'm trying to find it myself), however, if all the previous trials had some artifacts that was imputed to the discriminator, not I think it's working fine, except for some artifacts:

[image]

Those are:

- Ground truth
- segmentation
- Model generation

As you can see the right and bottom border have some artifacts, that I'm trying to find a fix for them

the generator is built like this (UNet):

- series of 2D conv 3x3 kernel, 2x2 strides, padding same (with batch norm before activation)
- series of 2D transpose conv 3x3 kernel, 2x2 strides, padding same (with residual connection from the encoder, just like UNet)
- some 2D transpose conv with various filters, to let the model still additionally change the decoder reconstruction

the decoder instead is a fully convolutional net with kernel 3x3 and strides 2x2

Now, I'm using "padding same" everywhere, that was my initial though on why those happens, however I changed to "same" and they are still here... at the moment, I think that this might be due to the different shapes of strides and kernels, however this idea don't quite hold

Any idea on what can be the artifact origin?

**Code:**
I leave the code for the 2 models, so that i maybe easier to understand.

Generator:

```
class TBNRConv(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters=128, kernel_size=(3, 3),strides=(1, 1),padding='same', use_bias=False, act=tf.nn.leaky_relu):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = K.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size,strides=strides,padding=padding, use_bias=use_bias)
        self.bn = K.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.act = act
    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        return x

class BNRConv(K.layers.Layer):
    def __init__(self, filters=128, kernel_size=(3,3), strides=(2,2), padding="same", use_bias=False, act=tf.nn.leaky_relu):
        super().__init__()
        self.conv = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=filters, kernel_size=kernel_size, strides=strides,padding=padding,use_bias=use_bias)
        self.bn = K.layers.BatchNormalization()
        self.act = act
    def call(self, inputs, *args, **kwargs):
        x = self.conv(inputs)
        x = self.bn(x)
        x = self.act(x)
        return x

image = K.layers.Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])
e_1 = BNRConv(strides=(1,1))(image)
e_2 = BNRConv(filters=64)(e_1)
e_2 = BNRConv(strides=(1,1))(e_2)
e_3 = BNRConv(filters=64)(e_2)
e_3 = BNRConv(strides=(1,1))(e_3)
e_4 = BNRConv(filters=64)(e_3)
e_4 = BNRConv(strides=(1,1))(e_4)
bottleneck = BNRConv()(e_4)

d_4 = TBNRConv(strides=(2,2))(bottleneck)
d_4 = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1))(d_4)
d_4 = K.layers.Add()([d_4, e_4])

d_3 = TBNRConv(strides=(2,2))(d_4)
d_3 = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1))(d_3)
d_3 = K.layers.Add()([d_3, e_3])

d_2 = TBNRConv(strides=(2,2))(d_3)
d_2 = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1))(d_2)
d_2 = K.layers.Add()([d_2, e_2])

d_1 = TBNRConv(strides=(2,2))(d_2)
d_1 = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1))(d_1)
d_1 = K.layers.Add()([d_1, e_1])

x = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1), kernel_size=(1,1), filters=64)(d_1)
x = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3), filters=64)(x)
x = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1), kernel_size=(5,5), filters=64)(x)
x = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1), kernel_size=(3,3), filters=64)(x)
x = TBNRConv(strides=(1,1), kernel_size=(1,1), filters=64)(x)
x = K.layers.Conv2DTranspose(filters=3, kernel_size=(3, 3), padding='same',use_bias=False, activation='tanh')(x)
generator = K.Model(inputs=[image], outputs=[x])
```

Discriminator:

```
image = K.layers.Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])
reference = K.layers.Input(shape=x_train.shape[1:])

y = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding="SAME")(reference)
y = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(y)
y = K.layers.Dropout(0.3)(y)
y = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding="SAME")(y)
y = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(y)

x = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding="SAME")(image)
x = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(x)
x = K.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, padding="SAME")(x)
x = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(x)

z = K.layers.Concatenate()([x, y])
z = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(z)
z = K.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
z = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(z)
z = K.layers.Dropout(0.2)(z)
z = K.layers.Conv2D(filters=16, kernel_size=(3,3), activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu, strides=(2,2), padding="SAME")(z)
z = K.layers.Dense(1, activation="sigmoid")(z)
discriminator = K.Model(inputs=[image, reference], outputs=[z])
```

Answer (score 1):

Torch implementations normally combat edge artifacts with 'reflect' padding, which is not present in TF. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50677544/reflection-padding-conv2d) has some possible implementations in its answers section.

Comment: So, in other words, it “mirrors” the images? Along the boundaries of the channles